# Application crashes on creating dynamic spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I do not know why this application crashes. I am trying to execute dynamic spinner for city and area. I want to automatically populate area spinner depending on city selected from first spinner. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

select_location_layout.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#C51162"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:text="@string/selectCity"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/citySpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/selectArea"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/areaSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

</LinearLayout>
```

LocationSelection.java

```
package com.pixalstudio.navigationdrawer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class LocationSelection extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.select_location_layout);

        Spinner citySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.citySpinner);
        Spinner areaSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.areaSpinner);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.cities, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        citySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(this, R.array.ahmedabad_area,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        areaSpinner.setAdapter(adapter1);

        citySpinner
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                            View view, int position, long id) {
                        adapter1.clear();

                        int stringArrayResource = 0;
                        switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            stringArrayResource = R.array.ahmedabad_area;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            stringArrayResource = R.array.baroda_area;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            stringArrayResource = R.array.surat_area;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            stringArrayResource = R.array.mumbai_area;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            stringArrayResource = R.array.pune_area;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            stringArrayResource = R.array.banglore_area;
                            break;
                        }

                        adapter1.addAll(getResources().getStringArray(
                                stringArrayResource));
                        adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                });
    }

}
```

Strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Navigation Drawer</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="drawer_open">Open Navigation Drawer</string>
    <string name="drawer_close">Close Navigation Drawer</string>
    <string name="selectCity">Select City</string>
    <string name="selectArea">Select Area</string>

    <string-array name="drawerItems">
        <item>Location</item>
        <item>Ready for Delivery</item>
        <item>Order Cake</item>
        <item>About us</item>
        <item>Setting</item>
        <item>Login</item>
        <item>My Orders</item>
        <item>My Cart</item>
        <item>Help</item>
        <item>Contact us</item>
        <item>Rate us</item>
        <item>Share</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="cities">
        <item>Ahmedabad</item>
        <item>Baroda</item>
        <item>Surat</item>
        <item>Mumbai</item>
        <item>Pune</item>
        <item>Banglore</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="ahmedabad_area">
        <item>Maninagar</item>
        <item>C.T.M</item>
        <item>C.G. Road</item>
        <item>Satellite</item>
        <item>S.G. Highway</item>
        <item>Navarangpura</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="baroda_area">
        <item>Alkapuri</item>
        <item>Fateganj</item>
        <item>Jaeahar Nagar</item>
        <item>Karali</item>
        <item>Mandavi</item>
        <item>Masar Road</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="surat_area">
        <item>Athwa</item>
        <item>Bajipura</item>
        <item>Cenral Colony</item>
        <item>Hajira</item>
        <item>Kamrej</item>
        <item>Lajpor</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="mumbai_area">
        <item>Adarsha Nagar</item>
        <item>Thane</item>
        <item>Centacruz</item>
        <item>Andheri</item>
        <item>Varsova</item>
        <item>Dadar</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="pune_area">
        <item>Akurdi</item>
        <item>Bavada</item>
        <item>Chakan</item>
        <item>Daund</item>
        <item>Earth Stn</item>
        <item>Ganeshkhind</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="banglore_area">
        <item>Indira Nagar</item>
        <item>Jay Nagar</item>
        <item>TipSandra</item>
        <item>Kora Mangala</item>
        <item>Rajaji Nagar</item>
        <item>White Field</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

LogCat

```
    07-08 09:43:59.546: D/OpenGLRenderer(3140): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
07-08 09:43:59.549: D/(3140): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb42d7750, tid 3140
07-08 09:43:59.610: D/Atlas(3140): Validating map...
07-08 09:43:59.727: D/libEGL(3140): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
07-08 09:43:59.727: D/libEGL(3140): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
07-08 09:43:59.745: D/libEGL(3140): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
07-08 09:43:59.774: D/(3140): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaf039480, tid 3158
07-08 09:43:59.888: I/OpenGLRenderer(3140): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-08 09:44:00.027: D/OpenGLRenderer(3140): Enabling debug mode 0
07-08 09:44:00.063: W/EGL_emulation(3140): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-08 09:44:00.063: W/OpenGLRenderer(3140): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaf035800, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-08 09:44:07.986: W/EGL_emulation(3140): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-08 09:44:07.986: W/OpenGLRenderer(3140): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb43d4c00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-08 09:44:08.032: D/AndroidRuntime(3140): Shutting down VM
07-08 09:44:08.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3140): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 09:44:08.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3140): Process: com.pixalstudio.navigationdrawer, PID: 3140
07-08 09:44:08.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3140): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
07-08 09:44:08.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3140):     at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:638)
07-08 09:44:08.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3140):     at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.remove(AbstractList.java:75)
07-08 09:44:08.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3140):     at java.util.AbstractList.removeRange(AbstractList.java:658)
07-08 09:44:08.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3140):     at java.util.AbstractList.clear(AbstractList.java:466)
07-08 09:44:08.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3140):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.clear(ArrayAdapter.java:258)
07-08 09:44:08.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3140):     at com.pixalstudio.navigationdrawer.LocationSelection$1.onItemSelected(LocationSelection.java:34)
07-08 09:44:08.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3140):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:914)
07-08 09:44:08.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3140):     at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:903)
07-08 09:44:08.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3140):     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$300(AdapterView.java:48)
07-08 09:44:08.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3140):     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:873)
07-08 09:44:08.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3140):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-08 09:44:08.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3140):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-08 09:44:08.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3140):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-08 09:44:08.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3140):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
07-08 09:44:08.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3140):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-08 09:44:08.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3140):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-08 09:44:08.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3140):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
07-08 09:44:08.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3140):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

NEW LOGCAT

```
    07-08 10:05:38.686: D/OpenGLRenderer(3587): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
07-08 10:05:38.694: D/(3587): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb42d7710, tid 3587
07-08 10:05:38.720: D/Atlas(3587): Validating map...
07-08 10:05:38.822: D/libEGL(3587): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
07-08 10:05:38.823: D/libEGL(3587): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
07-08 10:05:38.855: D/libEGL(3587): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
07-08 10:05:38.869: D/(3587): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaf039480, tid 3605
07-08 10:05:38.967: I/OpenGLRenderer(3587): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-08 10:05:39.104: D/OpenGLRenderer(3587): Enabling debug mode 0
07-08 10:05:39.278: W/EGL_emulation(3587): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-08 10:05:39.278: W/OpenGLRenderer(3587): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaf035800, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-08 10:05:39.335: W/ViewRootImpl(3587): Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_ALT_RIGHT, scanCode=100, metaState=META_ALT_ON|META_ALT_RIGHT_ON, flags=0x8, repeatCount=24909, eventTime=11265296, downTime=9978220, deviceId=1, source=0x301 }
07-08 10:05:39.339: W/ViewRootImpl(3587): Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_ALT_RIGHT, scanCode=100, metaState=META_ALT_ON|META_ALT_RIGHT_ON, flags=0x8, repeatCount=24910, eventTime=11265576, downTime=9978220, deviceId=1, source=0x301 }
07-08 10:05:39.340: I/Choreographer(3587): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-08 10:05:39.615: W/ViewRootImpl(3587): Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_ALT_RIGHT, scanCode=100, metaState=META_ALT_ON|META_ALT_RIGHT_ON, flags=0x8, repeatCount=24911, eventTime=11266094, downTime=9978220, deviceId=1, source=0x301 }
07-08 10:05:39.615: W/ViewRootImpl(3587): Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_ALT_RIGHT, scanCode=100, metaState=META_ALT_ON|META_ALT_RIGHT_ON, flags=0x8, repeatCount=24912, eventTime=11266144, downTime=9978220, deviceId=1, source=0x301 }
07-08 10:05:39.616: W/ViewRootImpl(3587): Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_ALT_RIGHT, scanCode=100, metaState=META_ALT_ON|META_ALT_RIGHT_ON, flags=0x8, repeatCount=24913, eventTime=11266373, downTime=9978220, deviceId=1, source=0x301 }
07-08 10:05:50.356: W/EGL_emulation(3587): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-08 10:05:50.356: W/OpenGLRenderer(3587): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb43d4be0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-08 10:05:50.383: W/ViewRootImpl(3587): Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_ALT_RIGHT, scanCode=100, metaState=META_ALT_ON|META_ALT_RIGHT_ON, flags=0x8, repeatCount=25119, eventTime=11276982, downTime=9978220, deviceId=1, source=0x301 }
07-08 10:05:50.389: W/ViewRootImpl(3587): Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_ALT_RIGHT, scanCode=100, metaState=META_ALT_ON|META_ALT_RIGHT_ON, flags=0x8, repeatCount=25120, eventTime=11277095, downTime=9978220, deviceId=1, source=0x301 }
07-08 10:05:50.429: D/AndroidRuntime(3587): Shutting down VM
07-08 10:05:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3587): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 10:05:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3587): Process: com.pixalstudio.navigationdrawer, PID: 3587
07-08 10:05:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3587): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
07-08 10:05:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3587):     at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:404)
07-08 10:05:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3587):     at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:425)
07-08 10:05:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3587):     at java.util.Collections.addAll(Collections.java:2583)
07-08 10:05:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3587):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.addAll(ArrayAdapter.java:211)
07-08 10:05:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3587):     at com.pixalstudio.navigationdrawer.LocationSelection$1.onItemSelected(LocationSelection.java:57)
07-08 10:05:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3587):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:914)
07-08 10:05:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3587):     at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:903)
07-08 10:05:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3587):     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$300(AdapterView.java:48)
07-08 10:05:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3587):     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:873)
07-08 10:05:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3587):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-08 10:05:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3587):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-08 10:05:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3587):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-08 10:05:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3587):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
07-08 10:05:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3587):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-08 10:05:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3587):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-08 10:05:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3587):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
07-08 10:05:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3587):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: tried removing that. didn't help. Okay sorry I think my question is wrong. actually the application launches successfully, but when I select an item form drawer list. it crashes. Let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say `adapter1.clear();` is illegal and throws:

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`

because something is iterating over a list. Because of this line in your trace at `com.pixalstudio.navigationdrawer.LocationSelection$1.onItemSelected(LocationSele‌​ction.java:34)`

Removing line 34 `adapter1.clear();`

new strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Navigation Drawer</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="drawer_open">Open Navigation Drawer</string>
    <string name="drawer_close">Close Navigation Drawer</string>
    <string name="selectCity">Select City</string>
    <string name="selectArea">Select Area</string>

</resources>
```

add `array.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="drawerItems">
        <item>Location</item>
        <item>Ready for Delivery</item>
        <item>Order Cake</item>
        <item>About us</item>
        <item>Setting</item>
        <item>Login</item>
        <item>My Orders</item>
        <item>My Cart</item>
        <item>Help</item>
        <item>Contact us</item>
        <item>Rate us</item>
        <item>Share</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="cities">
        <item>Ahmedabad</item>
        <item>Baroda</item>
        <item>Surat</item>
        <item>Mumbai</item>
        <item>Pune</item>
        <item>Banglore</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="ahmedabad_area">
        <item>Maninagar</item>
        <item>C.T.M</item>
        <item>C.G. Road</item>
        <item>Satellite</item>
        <item>S.G. Highway</item>
        <item>Navarangpura</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="baroda_area">
        <item>Alkapuri</item>
        <item>Fateganj</item>
        <item>Jaeahar Nagar</item>
        <item>Karali</item>
        <item>Mandavi</item>
        <item>Masar Road</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="surat_area">
        <item>Athwa</item>
        <item>Bajipura</item>
        <item>Cenral Colony</item>
        <item>Hajira</item>
        <item>Kamrej</item>
        <item>Lajpor</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="mumbai_area">
        <item>Adarsha Nagar</item>
        <item>Thane</item>
        <item>Centacruz</item>
        <item>Andheri</item>
        <item>Varsova</item>
        <item>Dadar</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="pune_area">
        <item>Akurdi</item>
        <item>Bavada</item>
        <item>Chakan</item>
        <item>Daund</item>
        <item>Earth Stn</item>
        <item>Ganeshkhind</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="banglore_area">
        <item>Indira Nagar</item>
        <item>Jay Nagar</item>
        <item>TipSandra</item>
        <item>Kora Mangala</item>
        <item>Rajaji Nagar</item>
        <item>White Field</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

new `LocationSelection.java`

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class LocationSelection extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.select_location_layout);

        Spinner citySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.citySpinner);
        Spinner areaSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.areaSpinner);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.cities, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        citySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        //create new ArrayAdapter without loading from resource... Loading from resource makes it final
        final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        areaSpinner.setAdapter(adapter1);

        citySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                adapter1.clear();

                int stringArrayResource = 0;
                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    stringArrayResource = R.array.ahmedabad_area;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    stringArrayResource = R.array.baroda_area;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    stringArrayResource = R.array.surat_area;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    stringArrayResource = R.array.mumbai_area;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    stringArrayResource = R.array.pune_area;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    stringArrayResource = R.array.banglore_area;
                    break;
                }

                adapter1.addAll(getResources().getStringArray(stringArrayResource));
                adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
    }

}
```

Comment: tried removing that. didn't help. Okay sorry I think my question is wrong. actually the application launches successfully, but when I select an item form drawer list. it crashes. Let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: According to the stacktrace it shouldn't start because it says `Shutting down VM` ... Seems final... And if it does start, without the VM, you need that... Can you post the stackTrace when you don't call list.clear? (maybe the `so`s start?)

Comment: what do you exactly mean to say? Sorry I am new to this. Let know what you need to solve this.

Comment: You said the same happens when you remove the `adapter1.clear();` method... Can you do that anyway, then copy the error trace (LogCat). Maybe there are 2 problems, of which the other one is obfuscated by the `UnsupportedOperationException` of the `ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1`... Btw, why would you want to empty a list, of which the values you just loaded?

Comment: Okay I am editing the fresh LogCat after removing adapter1.clear();

Comment: what happened? can you help?

Comment: Wait a sec.... Don't you mean `adapter` instead of `adapter1`? Since you set `adapter` to `citySpinner` and `adapter1` to `areaSpinner`, but set the onOnItemSele.... for `citySpinner`? Then you should be able to get the adapter from the citySpinner (out of my head) inside the onItemSelected `parent.getAdapter()`

Comment: I tried replacing 'adapter1' with 'adapter'. still it crashed. please please please help. I am stuck. :(

Comment: Now the problem is on line 57 `adapter.addAll()`... The ArrayAdapter is immutable, so no adding or deleting items from that list... I don't have a compiler where I'm now... But,,, if you want to add items to an Array, why not create a new one, then you have full control. change `final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(this, R.array.ahmedabad_area,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);` to `new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82716/discussion-between-akkie4396-and-danielson).